# Produce a graph from an editable table in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny application with the following ui:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui =  fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Tabsets"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Tabset w/ plot, summary, and table ----
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Summary", rHandsontableOutput('contents'),
                           actionButton("saveBtn", "Save changes")
                  ),
                  tabPanel("Tab",
                           rHandsontableOutput('contentFinal')),
                  tabPanel("Dashboard",
                           plotOutput('dashboard1'))




      )

    )
  )
)
```

And the following server

```
library(dplyr)
library(rhandsontable)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 9*1024^2)

server = function(input, output) {

  values <- reactiveValues()

  Post <- c("", "")
  list2 <- c(12,13)
  df <- data.frame(Post, list2)


  output$contents <- renderRHandsontable({

    rhandsontable(df, width = 550, height = 300) %>%    
      hot_col(col = "Post", type = "dropdown")
  })

  saveData <- eventReactive({input$saveBtn},{
    finalDF <- hot_to_r(input$contents)
    finalDF$Post <- ifelse(finalDF$Post =="",NA,finalDF$Post)
    newDF <- finalDF[complete.cases(finalDF),]
    return(newDF)
  })

  output$contentFinal <- renderRHandsontable(
    rhandsontable(saveData())
  )

  output$dashboard1 <- renderPlot(
    ggplot(input$contentFinal, aes(x = Post, y = list2 )) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity")

  )
  observeEvent(input$saveBtn, saveData())

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The flow is like this:

1. In the first tab, I bring up data with an empty post column
2. In this tab, I can add a name for the post and save it.
3. As soon as I save he rows with values for post become visible in the next tab.

Then the next thing I want to do is to have a visual in the dashboard tab that shows the data. Therefore I create:

```
output$dashboard1 <- renderPlot(

    ggplot(input$contentFinal, aes(x = Post, y = List2 )) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity")

  )
```

This however gives me the following ggplot2 errror:

> ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class list

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: when I try to run your code, I also get Warning: Error in ggplot: object 'finalDF' not found. Can you make it reproducible?

Comment: @MLavoie, I made a small error. Should be reproducible now!

Comment: it works for me if I replace ggplot(input$contentFinal, aes(x = Post, y = **List2** )) by ggplot(input$contentFinal, aes(x = Post, y = **list2** ))

Comment: @MLavoie, changed it. However if I try to edit two rows and put "Boot", "Boot" in the Post colum it still get: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class list. Any thoughts??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because `input$contentFinal` is handsontable data. We need to convert it to R object using `hot_to_r` function.

The ggplot should be plotted using the following:

`ggplot(hot_to_r(input$contentFinal), aes(x = Post, y = list2 )) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Hope it helps!

Comment: You forgot to include this in your code but it works :)